# The bones are very tiny

Tags: rigging

I imported my Downloaded model and found that the bones are very tiny. It was impossible to select one bone.
I tried to use other models and the same thing happens.
I reset my whole app by deleting the appdata but its still there.
When I checked my settings they were fine to me. I tried to do things in other answers from similar questions and they do not work. The bones still exist, but they're not in normal shape. I wonder if this issue has got to do with a bug/glitch.
I am sorry if this is obvious. I am just a beginner at blender.

[image]

[image]

Comment: We'll need far more details to answer that, preferably including images of what you have so far. For instance there's no such thing as an Eevee model! [How to ask a question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You'll still have to provide more details and images, preferable of the whole Blender window with your settings.

Comment: Hi. This question was put on hold because as it stands it is not answerable for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Remember only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it thoroughly only you know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Please describe in detail what your issue is, possibly supported by [some accompanying screenshots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) with the [edit] button above. Don't post a comment or ask a new question, editing will automatically put it up for review so it can be reopened.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will take note next time. I am new to this website so I apologize if I made a mistake.

Comment: If you're importing a .dae try toggling "Fix Leaf Bones" and "Find Bone Chains" on the import screen.

Comment: thanks, but how do I do that?